# extracting numbers whose lengths are fixed from text file

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file. This file includes characters and numbers as follows:

```
ANKR00TUR_R_20183240000_01D_30S_MO.rnx:  2018    11    20    00    00    0.0000000     GPS         TIME OF FIRST OBS
brmu3350.14o:  2014    12     1     0     0    0.0000000     GPS         TIME OF FIRST OBS
KNY12040.14o:  2014     7    23     0     0    0.0000000     GPS         TIME OF FIRST OBS
rinex_quantity:grep "TIME OF FIRST OBS" * > time_of_first_epochs
```

I need to extract only 4 digits numbers and store them into another file as follows:

```
2018
2014
2014
```

I applied the following code but it extracts all 4 digit numbers:

```
grep  -Po "\d{4}" data

2018
3240
2018
0000
3350
2014
0000
1204
2014
0000
```

Comment: you need to extract the digit number after the colon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `grep` command was almost correct, you just have to anchor the pattern to match only if there is a word boundary before or after it.

Word boundaries are zero-length patterns that match between a word-character (letters, digits, underscore) and a non-word charater (e.g. spaces, other punctuation, line end, and everything else).

In `grep`, you can either do this by surrounding your pattern with `\b`, or by using the `-w` switch to enable word matching:

```bsh
$ grep -Po '\b\d{4}\b' data
2018
2014
2014

$ grep -Pow '\d{4}' data
2018
2014
2014
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) ([docs](https://miller.readthedocs.io/)) is:

```
mlr --implicit-csv-header --pprint  cut -f 2 then label year input
```

As output you will have

```
year
2014
2014
```

Mi input is

```
brmu3350.14o:  2014    12     1     0     0    0.0000000     GPS         TIME OF FIRST OBS
KNY12040.14o:  2014     7    23     0     0    0.0000000     GPS         TIME OF FIRST OBS
```

I have simply extracted the second column with cut